# Вставка подстроки в строку

Tags: c++

Обзавелся задачкой, нужно получить имя пользователя и затем его вставить в строку. Вопрос: как это сделать?

Код:

```
DWORD size = 1024;
char buf[1024];
GetUserName(buf, &size);
char* path;
path = "C:\\Users\\" + buf + "\\Desktop";
cout << path;
```

Должно получиться так:

> ```
> C:\Users\Example-PC\Desktop
> ```

Но возникают ошибки:

> ```
> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
> Error C2110 '+': cannot add two pointers
> ```

Comment: @Aleksei .C вместо `char*` напишите `std::string` и у Вас все заработает.

Comment: Изменил char* на std::string не помогло, 1 ошибка даже добавилась. 
Error (active) no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists

Comment: Получил желаемый ответ, всего лишь надо использовать strcat().

Comment: значит либо не весь код показали, либо не там поменяли. В любом случае - если пишете на c++, то strcat немного не то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь сложить *указатели*, а не строки. Для компилятора нет особой разницы какой этой указатель: `char*`, `int*` или некий абстрактный `T*`. Чтобы выполнять конкатенацию двух сишных нуль-терминированных строк (которые де-факто являются `char*`) следует использовать функцию `strcat`. Для Вашего случая нужно завести дополнительный массив (помимо `buf`), а не просто указатель, и выполнять склейку в него, например:

```
char path[1024] = "C:\\Users\\"; 
strcpy(path, buf);
strcpy(path, "\\Desktop");
```

Также можно воспользоваться функцией `sprintf`. В любом случае, дополнительно имеет смысл проверять отсутствие выхода за границы выделенной памяти.

Однако, для c++ кода (если это возможно) стоит отказаться от си-строк и использовать типы наподобие `std::string`, для которых имеются соответствующие перегрузки операторов и можно выполнять конкатенацию просто и очевидно, не отвлекаясь на задачи по контролю памяти. Пример:

```
std::string path = "C:\\Users\\" + std::string(buf) + "\\Desktop";
cout << path;
```